# Filtering with NA values required

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` with 20 columns in which I need to apply certain filters. There is a column named `price`, which has many NA values and other numeric values. I want to filter the data such that I keep the NA values as well as the values satisfying my filter.

```
df<-df[(df$item="Buckets" & df$cutomers>50 & df$price>100),]
```

now this returns 1000 values which is right and out of which 100 values are NA. But instead of showing NA in just price column, all the columns like item,customers etc. become NA automatically. I want to filter so that I get all `price>100` and include NA values as well.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood, but if you want to retain all the NAs in `price` but exclude the rest, a `dplyr` solution could be

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
     filter(item == "Buckets" & customers > 50 & price > 50 | is.na(price))
```

Note that `dplyr::filter()` drops NAs from the filtered variables automatically unless you specify it, so in this case, you have to explicitly say you **don't** want to drop them from `price`

Answer (score 1):

we can use `|` (`or`) to keep na values also;

```
df<-df[(df$item=="Buckets" & df$cutomers>50 & (df$price>100 | is.na(df$price))),]
```